# Braze <> Snowflake Integration

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, braze

I have a table that has the following information:

| UPDATED_AT | EXTERNAL ID | VIEWS | CLICKS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/12/2023 | 1 | 100 | 100 |

I am trying to integrate this data from snowflake into Braze using the following instructions (https://www.braze.com/docs/user_guide/data_and_analytics/cloud_ingestion/integrations/#step-1-set-up-tables-or-views). I have the UPDATED_AT and EXTERNAL ID columns already but I need to convert the VIEWS and CLICKS into a JSON to insert it into the PAYLOAD area. How can I convert VIEWS and CLICKS into a JSON to make it look like

{ "VIEWS": "100", "CLICKS":"100"}

For every row in my database? Would appreciate the help!

So the updated database should look like:

| UPDATED_AT | EXTERNAL ID | PAYLOAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/12/2023 | 1 | { "VIEWS": "100", "CLICKS":"100"} |

Comment: Just use the OBJECT_CONSTRUCT function

Comment: Resolved using OBJECT_CONSTRUCT. Thank you!